# MutableList inside JSONArray in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

Consider this code in Kotlin:

```
var test = JSONArray()
test.put(mutableListOf(1, 2, 22, 15, 56))

//var test2 = ??? //sets value of test2 to 15
```

What exactly should I put into the ??? for test2 to return the value 15? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you perhaps post the JSON you're trying to assemble? Your question is very unclear as it is.

Comment: the JSONArray() is going to be one that holds mutable lists, so the code is going to be like test.put(mutableListOf(2,5, 55, 66, 77, 100)), and then test.put(mutableListOf(22, 15)) and test.put(mutableListOf(1,22, 81, 44)) and so  on. Think of it as a JSONArray that holds the ages of occupants in each household. 

I just want a code to be able to retrieve the fourth number of the first mutable list stored inside this JSONArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
val firstList = test[0] as List<Int>
val fourthElement = firstList[3] // 15
```

Note that you need to handle various exceptions here.

- The first element might not be a `List<Int>`. If it's not a `List` at all, the initial cast will fail, if it's a `List` but it doesn't contain `Int` values, reading the fourth element will cause a cast exception.
- There might not be an element in the first list at index `3`, which can also result in an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you want to get the number 15 from JSONArray and MutableList.
I think this would help you:

```
var mutableList = test.get(0)
var test2 = mutableList.get(3)
```

3 is index of 15 in the mutable list.

Comment: Hi. I tried your code but it gave me an unresolved reference error in var test2 = mutableList.get(3)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `org.json` one, the safest way would be:

```
val test = JSONArray()
test.put(mutableListOf(1, 2, 22, 15, 56))

val test2 = test.getJSONArray(0).getNumber(3)
println(test2)
```